# How do I prevent endermen from teleporting on the top of my XP farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In my Minecraft world, I have an enderman XP farm, which I (obviously) use to fix my weapons, tools and armor. It's my model (no tutorial used), and it works just fine... except the fact that endermen teleport to the top because of fall damage. This gets very annoying after a while (mainly because it reaches the mob cap faster).

To try to fix this, I have placed slabs (seen in the screenshot) to try to prevent them from teleporting. The only thing that it does is make my farm go faster (which I really like), but they still teleport anyway.

So, the question I have is: ***How can I prevent endermen from teleporting at the top of my XP farm?***

## Screenshot

[image: ss of endermen teleporting on top of farm]

Comment: One way I tend to do is to place double carpets i.e. a carpet with a carpet on top of that one. That has always worked for me, but I can't say for sure that that will work. You can also check to see if there are other available blocks nearby that they tp to and then walk to the roof, just an idea.

Comment: Xisuma has had a video series until a few years ago called "Mythbusting", in which, among other things, it was tested which blocks endermen can teleport to (multiple times, because of new blocks in updates). Probably most of it still applies today. Alternatively: water.

Comment: Double carpets or waterlogged blocks should do the trick, unfortunately Endermen can't spawn on non-solid blocks but they can teleport on them, so half slabs don't work as you discovered.

Comment: Dripstone? It could be expensive...

Answer (score -1):

After reviewing the question, I would suggest that you place water on the area. If you place torches I think it should work. I play bedrock but it still works for both editions.

Comment: If your answer is for Bedrock Edition, then don't answer it. Only put the answer if you know what it is.

Comment: I know, it still works on Java as I've played Java before and know how it works.

Comment: But here's the thing: I'm not asking about endermen spawning, I'm talking about endermen *teleporting*.

Comment: Oh, I see. You could put dispenser constantly shooting arrows but that would be uneffective.

Comment: A better way would just be water logged blocks.